# AJAX Request Error POST 0 () In Chrome Console Log

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I occasionally got this error in chrome console log `POST https://example.com/example 0 ()`

[image: ajax request error post 0 ()]

There's no information at all about the error.

What it is mean?

How to see more information about the error and how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is this caused by. I am getting it sometimes too. But the error is gone when I reconnect to the internet.

EDIT:

This error is shown when there is no internet connection. For me the issue was that I was subscribing to the network connection and was doing call right on the event which was giving me mentioned error. I found out that this is too soon even if event on connected was already triggered and web app is not yet connected. Delay one second after the event solved this for me. My project is Angular Ionic android / iOS app.